# transliterate arabic names to latin characters

Tags: google-api, google-translate

Because

> The [Google Transliterate API](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started) has been officially deprecated as of May
>   26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy.

I'm using [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text) to transliterate arabic names into latin characters, using "english" as a target language.

This works for names like "رياض" which become "riad".

The problem is that some arabic names have a meaning,

e.g.  "كامل" becomes "full" instead of "kamel"

Funny enough, this doesn't always apply. For example, my name "شادي" gets translated into "shady" instead of "singer". Even in a context such as "أَنا شادي الأَلحان" where it could be translated into "I am a singer of melodies", it becomes "I'm Shady Tunes"

- Is there any other API that I'm missing that would accomplish this?
- Or is there an option that I can pass into the Translate API to tell it to just to transliterate?
- Or perhaps a `source language` being `arabic names` instead of `arabic`?

Edit: python code to exemplify

```
from google.cloud import translate
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path/to/gcp/key.json"
translate_client = translate.Client()
my_trans = lambda text: translate_client.translate(text, target_language='en')['translatedText']

list(map(my_trans, ["رياض", "شادي",  "كامل"]))
```

output is

```
['Riad', 'Shady', 'Full']
```

Answer (score 4):

By trial and error, passing the arabic for 'my name is "kamel akiki"'

```
my_trans('أَنا إِسمي "كامل عَقيقي"')
```

would give the name without translating the meaning to

```
'My name is &quot;Kamel Akiki&quot;'
```

and then I can just extract whatever is between the quotes